# Copy data from grouped table to CSV while keeping original columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I have some data in a table that undergoes a `GROUP BY` and `SUM`, then is copied to a csv file. However, in the csv file, the original group columns are not preserved and instead gives some sort of aggregation of the group by columns like this:

```
row                      site_el   site_ng
(2014, com, p125, 4A)     -125.4         0
(2014, res, p125, 4A)     -221.1     -2994
(2016, com, p125, 4A)      196.1         0
(2016, res, p125, 4A)     -299.8     -1833
```

My SQL query is:

```
COPY(
    SELECT year, sector, pca, clim_zone, SUM(site_el_per_bldg) as site_el, SUM(site_ng_per_bldg) as site_ng
    FROM results_20161107.outputs
    GROUP BY year, sector, pca, clim_zone
)
TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER;
```

I'd like to have my csv file include the four group by columns, ending up something like this:

```
year    sector      pca    clim_zone    site_el   site_ng
2014       com     p125           4A     -125.4         0
2014       res     p125           4A     -221.1     -2994
2016       com     p125           4A      196.1         0
2016       res     p125           4A     -299.8     -1833
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The output looks like you used parentheses around those columns, e.g: `SELECT (year, sector, pca, clim_zone), sum() .. FROM ...`

Comment: Ah yes, that was the case...I was implementing this in Python and had something like `(%(group_cols)s)` and didn't notice those extra parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggests you used parentheses around those columns, e.g:

```
COPY (
    SELECT ( year, sector, pca, clim_zone ), 
           SUM(site_el_per_bldg) as site_el, 
           SUM(site_ng_per_bldg) as site_ng
    FROM results_20161107.outputs
    GROUP BY year, sector, pca, clim_zone
)
TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER;
```

The expression `(year, sector, pca, clim_zone)` creates a single column with an anonymous record as the column's type. The output you are seeing is the default text representation of a record type.